# Prove that $|J_0(x)| \le 1$ by using $J_0(x)=\frac{2}{\pi} \int_0^\frac{\pi}{2} \cos(x\sin(t)) \, dt$

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, bessel-functions

I'm reading a book on ordinary differential and I'm stuck on one of the exercises.

> 8. (a) Verify that
>    $$J_0(x)=\frac{2}{\pi} \int_0^\frac{\pi}{2} \cos(x\sin(t)) \, dt$$
>    (b) Deduce from the formula of part (a) that $|J_0(x)| \le 1$ for $x\ge0$

The integral representation in the question is a special case of a more general integral representation for the Bessel function and I know there are several proofs of that already, however I would like to know a more direct proof for the integral in the question. I really don't any idea on where to start, but I guess one could try to show that the integral is a solution to
$$x^2y''+xy'+x^2y=0$$
The second part I'm sure is easy to solve using some integration rules, but I'm quite a beginner so I don't what to do.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: $|\cos y|\le1$.

Comment: @AnginaSeng Thanks. Can you quickly check my reasoning here: Because $|\cos y|\le1$, the maximum area we could possibly have is a rectangle having the value of $1\cdot\frac{\pi}{2}$ and the because of the constant factor in front of the integral we get the maximum value of $1$. Is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second part b) is trivial. For the first part you have $$x^2y'' + xy' + x^2y \\
=-x^2 \int_0^{\pi/2} \cos(x\sin t) \sin^2 t \, {\rm d}t - x \int_0^{\pi/2} \sin(x\sin t) \sin t \, {\rm d}t + x^2 \int_0^{\pi/2} \cos(x\sin t) \, {\rm d}t \\
=x^2 \int_0^{\pi/2} \cos(x\sin t) \cos^2 t \, {\rm d}t + x\left\{ \sin(x\sin t) \cos t \Big|_0^{\pi/2} - x\int_0^{\pi/2} \cos(x\sin t) \cos^2 t \, {\rm d}t \right\} =0$$

Comment: Thank you! Nothing is too trivial for me XD, but Angina Seng already helped with (b).